# C#/WPF Textbox error : "Value '' cannot be converted", TargetNull not working

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, targetnullvalue

I have a `Listview` and a `Textbox`binded to the selected item.
When the user deletes the value in the textbox (which is a double), I get the following error :  `Value '' cannot be converted`. So I had `TargetNullValue=''`, like this :

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBoxVoltage" Text="{Binding Voltage, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, TargetNullValue=''}" />
```

But I still get the error....What am I doing wrong ? Thanks.

Comment: I don't get the error with this.

If you try it like this do you still receive the error?

`TargetNullValue={x:Static system:String.Empty}` where `system` is the namespace mapping `xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"`

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work for me. Still get the error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is that your `Voltage` is of the type `double` and `''` cannot be converted to double.

You can change the `Voltage` type to `double?` which will allow you to do this.

---

The alternative is using a converter, but then assuming `0` and empty are the same thing:

```
public class EmptyDoubleConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null || (double)value == default(double))
            return "";

        return value.ToString();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value as string))
            return default(double);

        return double.Parse(value.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Great ! Thank you, `double?` works. What is it ? A nullable double ?

Comment: Yes, a nullable double. So it can be converted to a empty string.

Comment: And it seems to work with `integer`as well. Wonderful ! Thanks.